# Parameterized class declaration error in UVM

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, uvm, questasim, synopsys-vcs

I'm trying to use a parameterized class extended from uvm_object.

```
class som_util #(int entry_w=2) extends uvm_object;
 `uvm_object_utils(som_util)
 "Some other static functions using the parameterized variables"
endclass
```

When I run my tests on IUS using this utility function, it compiles and the overall tests passes too. But on VCS , it complains with the Identifier "entry_w" is not defined ?

What could be the possible reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Parameterized classes in the UVM must be registered using the `uvm_object_param_utils` macro as below:

```
 `uvm_object_param_utils(som_util#(entry_w))
```

For more background, please see [my discussion](http://go.mentor.com/mcem) on this topic.